# Strange "AimTarget_GetTagPos" error in MW2

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I just got the error:

`AimTarget_GetTagPos: cannot find tag[j_helmet] on entity`

Anyone have any idea what this means?

Circumstances:

```
Lots of lag... error.
```

Comment: Do you at least know what circumstances triggered the error? Anything that might explain how you got it?

Comment: From the looks of the error message, this is probably a bug in the AI programming (oftentimes these days, video game AI is programmed in scripting languages).  Likely, there's nothing any of us can do for you - just email a bug report to the devs, giving as much information about what you were doing and what the error said as possible, and restart.

Answer (score 6):

Though not helpful, Some assumptions can be made:

`AimTarget_GetTagPos` - Likely this is refering to the hitbox (or target area) that you are currently targeting (with your reticle)

`tag[j_helmet]` - I'm out on a limb here, but I'm guessing this is refering to the helmet area of a person.  Now why this is importaint is that MW2 likely calculates damage different if you're hit in the helmet area as opposed to the face area (or whatever they call it)

So the full error in plain english would read something like:

> Game could not find the helmet on your current target

As to the implications of why this happened.  I'm going to say that somebody is running some kind of hack (or mod) that is masking their avatar's head, thus preventing headshots.  Or just a poorly put together hack that failed to cover some system check.

*tl:dr*

MW2 is constantly being hacked, so it's likely some leftover junk from one of those.  Reset your xbox and it shouldn't be a problem (unless you pick up the hack again)

Comment: Oh... so that explains why I kept headshotting people I couldn't see... :-p

Comment: It's more likely a bug than a hack.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft - Given MW2's history, either are likely...

Comment: Dammit I loved that game before hackers ruined it. I had 8 days play time and was level 46 prestige 2 before I got into a hacked lobby and got instantly and irreversibly upgraded to level 70 prestige 10. I hate hackers

Answer (score -2):

It's a hack where the person is headless and if you look at them or they look at you it lags you out of the game and gives you that error code.

Comment: This was already covered by the existing answer, nearly four years ago.